# How to change color of text underline in svg text element?

Tags: svg, text-decorations

```
<text
    x={width / 2}
    y={0}
    fill={fontColor}
    fontSize={30}
    fontWeight={700}
    textAnchor='middle'
    textDecoration='underline'
{titleText}</text>
```

We have an  that includes a  element that is underlined, and we'd like to change the color of the underline. This doesn't seem easy? There is no `textDecorationColor` with SVG  as there is in CSS for HTML. Any recommendations?

Although beggers cannot be choosers, calculating width of the text to use in a line element rendered below the text, or using an HTML ForeignObject, both seem suboptimal.

Edit - perhaps a duplicate, [Text decoration of a text svg in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76894327/text-decoration-of-a-text-svg-in-html?rq=2), with `foreignObject` the proposed solution in this other posting. I will likely go with this route.

Comment: In short: you need to calculate the text length and append a geometry element like 
 `<line>` to emulate an underline. Unfortunately, svg's `<text>` element is kinda "lost" – no line-wrapping and no reason to believe that's going to change anytime soon. At least you can use the quite [advanced interface](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#InterfaceSVGTextContentElement) to retrieve text or character positions.